# regex - How to match email:password regex combination only in the first 10 lines by ignoring the rest of the long text

Tags: python, regex

I'm quite new to using regex and I'm trying to match email:password combinations in a long text using regex and below is the working regex I use for my requirement and I currently have a set of long text files to look for a possible match.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+[*:]+(\b\w{5,}\b)
```

However I wanted to know how could I match only the first 10 lines of my text. I want my regex to return a match only if there are email:password combinations in the first 10 lines and ignore the rest of the text. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 Email : test@hotmail.com
 Password : password94
 Combo : test@hotmail.com:password94
 Plan : Premium
 Screens : 4
 HD : true
 UHD : true
 Expires in : 11-06-2019
 Country : en-PH
 NetFlix Checker | by xRisky
 Combo : test2@hotmail.com:password96
 Combo : test1@hotmail.com:password95
```

For example I only want to match the first email:pass combo in the 3rd line and not the ones in line 11 and 12

Comment: Which flavor/engine? Also, while the rules for email are clear, what are the rules for password? Finally, please show a piece of your data input.

Comment: I'm currently using python. As of now I'm just assuming passwords to be something that appears after an email and a colon and having atleast 5 characters since my dataset is  quite unstructured and I'm not looking for a perfect password regex. So I'm filtering out matches that has a email: followed by a string. I just wanted to match the first 10 to 15 lines of my text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I ran your code, it only returns empty lists, maybe the reason is because of this part:

```
(\b\w{5,}\b)
```

Actually, after the colon, the password could be anything, so I changed the password to:

```
.+
```

Here is my way:

```
import re
a = '''Email : test@hotmail.com
Password : password94
Combo : test@hotmail.com:password94
Plan : Premium
Screens : 4
HD : true
UHD : true
Expires in : 11-06-2019
Country : en-PH
NetFlix Checker | by xRisky
Combo : test2@hotmail.com:password96
Combo : test1@hotmail.com:password95'''
i = 0
for line in a.split('\n'):

    found = re.findall('[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+[*:]+.+',line)

    if found and i<=10:
        print(found)
    i+=1
```

Output:

```
['test@hotmail.com:password94']
['test2@hotmail.com:password96']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the text in question is being stored as a single string, you can reduce that to just the first 10 lines through a combination of splitting, splicing and joining:

```
my_text_reduced = "\n".join(my_text.split("\n")[:10])
```

That said, you might want to fix up your regex pattern a bit; for example I can't help but notice that you haven't escaped the periods in it. The period is actually a special regex character that matches *all* possible characters, so your pattern would match email addresses with invalid characters in its current state. You could also replace a-zA-Z0-9_ with just \w to clean it up a little.